# cant upload files through DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

my model.py

```
class HNUsers(models.Model):
    USERTYPE = (
        ...
    )

    GENDER = (
        (u'M', u'Male'),
        (u'F', u'Female'),
        (u'O', u'Other'),
    )
    f_name = models.CharField("Full Name", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    .
..
.
.
. More fields
```

my views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def user_api_v2(request):
    """
        This method returns .....

        """


    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        print(data)
        try:

            user = HNUsers.objects.get(
                Q(username=data['username']) | Q(email=data['email']) | Q(mobile_number=data['mobile_number']))

            return Response({"message": "User exists" }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except HNUsers.DoesNotExist :
            serializer = UserSerializer_v2(data=data)

            if serializer.is_valid():

                serializer.save()
                #return Response({'success': True, 'id': user.id, 'username': user.username, 'city': user.city, 'country': user.country, 'full_name': user.full_name, 'email': user.email, 'profile_img_url': user.profile_img_url}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                return Response({"message": "User created"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       # return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

MY serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer_v2(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    first_img = serializers.FileField()
    class Meta:
        model = HNUsers
        fields = [
            'hnid',
            'email',
            'mobile_number',
            'f_name',
            'date_of_birth',
            'gender',
            'country',
            'city',
            'first_img_url',
            'username',
            'first_img',
        ]
```

While I can create new user without uploading image but I want to upload the file with it .
If I try to upload file POSTMAN response with the following error
JSON parse error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 1124: invalid start byte"

Here is the POSTMAN error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [MultiPartParser](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser) for parsing multipart HTML form content, which supports file uploads.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser]) #add parser class
def user_api_v2(request):
```

Comment: Tried but have the same problem .. still shows same response

Comment: For debugging use FileUploadParser instead of Multiparser and upload(without other data, ie only file filed in form) a file, see whether  it work.

Comment: see this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser

Comment: No .. I am still trying but no luck :/ .. is there anyway I can connect you with ?